# How to get a private key given a certificate file with Java

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, private-key, public-key

I want to determine what a public key is given a certificate file(`something.cer` file), this is my Java code:

```
public class X509Read {
private static String hex(String  binStr) {
    String newStr = new String();
        try {
            String hexStr = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            byte [] p = binStr.getBytes();
            for(int k=0; k < p.length; k++ ){
                int j = ( p[k] >> 4 )&0xF;
                newStr = newStr + hexStr.charAt( j );
                j = p[k]&0xF;
                newStr = newStr + hexStr.charAt( j ) + " ";
            }   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to convert into hex values: " + e);
        } 
        return newStr;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String CA_Data[]=new String [15];
    String field;
    try{
        InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\123.cer");
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = 
            (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
        field=cert.getType().toString();
        CA_Data[0]=field;
        System.out.println("Type : "+field);
        field=Integer.toString(cert.getVersion());
        CA_Data[1]=field;
        System.out.println("Version : "+field);
        field=cert.getSubjectX500Principal().toString();
        CA_Data[2]=field;
        System.out.println("Name : "+field);
        field=cert.getSerialNumber().toString(16);
        CA_Data[3]=field;
        System.out.println("SerialNumber : "+field);
        field=cert.getSubjectAlternativeNames().toString();
        CA_Data[4]=field;
        System.out.println("SubjectAlternativeNames : "+field);
        field=cert.getNotBefore().toString();
        CA_Data[5]=field;
        System.out.println("NotBefore : "+field);
        field=cert.getNotAfter().toString();
        CA_Data[6]=field;
        System.out.println("NotAfter : "+field); 
        field=cert.getIssuerX500Principal().toString();
        CA_Data[7]=field;
        System.out.println("IssuerDN : "+field);
        field=cert.getSigAlgName().toString();
        CA_Data[8]=field;
        System.out.println("SigAlgName : "+field);
        byte [] tempPub = null;
        String sPub = null;
        RSAPublicKey pubkey = (RSAPublicKey) cert.getPublicKey();
        tempPub = pubkey.getEncoded();
        sPub = new String( tempPub );
        field=cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm();
        CA_Data[9]=field;
        System.out.println("Public Key Algorithm : " + field);
        field=hex(sPub);
        CA_Data[10]=field;
        System.out.println("Public key : \n" + field );        
        inStream.close();   
        }catch(Exception exception){ 
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And it get this data: `30 EF BF BD 01 22 30 0D 06 09 2A EF BF BD 48 EF BF BD EF BF BD 0D 01 01 01 05 00 03 EF BF BD 01 0F 00 30 EF BF BD 01 0A 02 EF BF BD 01 01 00 CA BF 19 EF BF BD 24 EF BF BD 2F EF BF BD 6A EF BF BD EF BF BD 4C EF BF BD 2C EF BF BD 30 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 7D EF BF BD 11 EF BF BD EF BF BD 7E EF BF BD 32 EF BF BD EF BF BD 42 73 EF BF BD EF BF BD 07 EF BF BD 15 EF BF BD 1D EF BF BD 00 39 33 66 4D 56 EF BF BD 67 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 19 EF BF BD 17 64 EF BF BD 24 19 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 15 EF BF BD EF BF BD C3 8C 3A EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 05 2D 3D C5 81 EF BF BD EF BF BD 48 71 EF BF BD 43 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD DE AE 20 EF BF BD EF BF BD 2B EF BF BD 1D D4 AE EF BF BD EF BF BD 25 EF BF BD 39 7B EF BF BD 70 0D 76 EF BF BD EF BF BD 7F 25 18 EF BF BD 22 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 27 EF BF BD 0F EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD DA 93 EF BF BD 0A 2C 03 3B EF BF BD 79 30 53 EF BF BD EF BF BD 26 30 EF BF BD 1D 3C 69 4C 20 EF BF BD 36 EF BF BD EF BF BD 41 7F EF BF BD 60 6B 58 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 18 EF BF BD EF BF BD 01 6E 64 7F EF BF BD 5F 3B EF BF BD 7B 25 C9 83 43 15 EF BF BD 6F 78 EF BF BD 21 EF BF BD EF BF BD 38 59 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 0B EF BF BD EF BF BD DE 9B 37 43 22 6A EF BF BD 15 28 EF BF BD 39 12 54 2B 38 4B EF BF BD 0A 43 67 0B 48 EF BF BD 59 02 60 57 EF BF BD 54 EF BF BD 6A 55 CE 91 EF BF BD 5A EF BF BD 78 76 66 13 EF BF BD 72 27 0A EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 0B 3E EF BF BD D2 9F EF BF BD 0E 4F EF BF BD EE B6 A5 5B EF BF BD 11 02 03 01 00 01`

But the correct public key is (Double-click the *.cer file)

[image]

`30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 ca bf 19 98 24 af 2f 8c 6a 94 e0 4c 9e 2c 86 30 9a 93 94 c5 7d f7 11 d8 e5 7e 8e 32 9d 90 42 73 99 ef 07 ed 15 a6 1d ff 00 39 33 66 4d 56 ee 67 9d 93 fd 19 f9 17 64 d9 24 19 de e3 d5 15 8a aa c3 8c 3a a7 d6 ec 05 2d 3d c5 81 da d0 48 71 d9 43 f1 e5 82 fc de ae 20 cc e3 2b c5 1d d4 ae eb a3 e3 93 25 e6 39 7b 8d 70 0d 76 b8 c0 7f 25 18 9d 22 b6 d8 ff 27 9e 0f f6 fe c4 da 93 9d 0a 2c 03 3b 80 79 30 53 c9 d0 26 30 9c 1d 3c 69 4c 20 80 36 a8 99 41 7f 99 60 6b 58 b0 84 a3 18 8b b8 01 6e 64 7f bc 5f 3b ce 7b 25 c9 83 43 15 af 6f 78 fa 21 c0 b7 38 59 90 b9 82 e0 0b f1 f6 de 9b 37 43 22 6a fb 15 28 da 39 12 54 2b 38 4b b8 0a 43 67 0b 48 9f 59 02 60 57 e6 89 54 dd 6a 55 ce 91 ad 5a f2 78 76 66 13 86 72 27 0a 94 82 a5 81 be 0b 3e fc d2 9f e0 0e 4f ba ee b6 a5 5b f9 11 02 03 01 00 01`

I know EF BF BD is a replacement character when I transform the Binary to Hex.

1. How do I get the correct public key?
2. How to get the private key?

Comment: You can't. The private key isn't there. Otherwise it wouldn't be private, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extend [Uwe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17300024/474189), the reason you see different values is your strange handling of the public key data:

```
RSAPublicKey pubkey = (RSAPublicKey) cert.getPublicKey();
tempPub = pubkey.getEncoded();
sPub = new String( tempPub );
field=hex(sPub);
System.out.println("Public key : \n" + field );
```

Here you are creating a string from a stream of bytes (never a good idea) and then hex-encoding the result. No wonder it looks weird! In fact, your `hex` method looks very strange and probably should be thrown away.

Instead, just try this:

```
RSAPublicKey pubkey = (RSAPublicKey) cert.getPublicKey();
field = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(pubkey.getEncoded());
System.out.println("Public key : \n" + field );
```

If you are using Java 5 or below, Google for a decent byte-to-hex function as `DatatypeConverter` is not available.

Comment: @user2452153  how can i get private key from certification in java code ?

Answer (score 7):

To get the public key simply use the methd `getPublicKey()` from `X509Certificate`.

The private key cannot be retrieved from the certificate as it is not included.

Answer (score 0):

The private key is stored on authentication server, which should not be read by clients.